# For running Java applications we used Tomcat7 and JBoss in Openshift, Is WebSockets enabled for this ? please help me

Tags: openshift, openshift-client-tools

var serviceLocation = "ws://kghgk.rhcloud.com:8000/chat?name=frank";

**I am getting the response in Browser while hitting that link**

```html
Request URL:ws://kghgk.rhcloud.com:8000/chat?name=hlhj
Request Method:GET
Status Code:101 Switching Protocols
Request Headersview source
Connection:Upgrade
Host:kghjk.rhcloud.com:8000
Origin:http://kghjk.rhcloud.com
Sec-WebSocket-Key:EX0+ZalV4q8q+DihpEQSdA==
Sec-WebSocket-Version:13
Upgrade:websocket
(Key3):00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00
Query String Parametersview URL encoded
name:hlhj
Response Headersview source
Connection:Upgrade
Sec-WebSocket-Accept:l8FzoRO13fp8LMa/6iBg6etSzq0=
Upgrade:websocket
(Challenge Response):00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00
```

I am getting null response . please help me to sove this . Is websockets really support for Tomcat7 and JBoss in openshift ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to this (https://github.com/openshift/origin-server/blob/master/cartridges/openshift-origin-cartridge-jbossews/metadata/manifest.yml) websockets should be enabled.  Does this work locally on your own development server?

You might also try using WildFly instead of Tomcat and see if that gives you better results with websockets.

Comment: Deployed in WildFly . Everything was going good . But Sometime Websocket is not working properly. Then again Everytime i am logging in **Openshift Site**  and Restarting the application. After that it working fine. After sometime again websocket not working . Please help me to solve this. How to keep the application always working Condition in OPENSHIFT  ??